# ios5 application - missing documents directory data - icloud

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, document, icloud

I m facing an issue where the database file in documents directory lost all the data after the device is kept idle for some time. iPhone has the iCloud subscription, and in the iCloud settings the app is set to use iCloud storage and backup.

But the application is not set up with iCloud provisioning profile, entitlements or anything in the code. I mean nothing is modified from the perspective of the application to use icloud features.

In this scenario how does the icloud behave with the application. The reason that the application document directory data getting lost - is it related to iCloud?

Thanks